# Bootvis is great, is there any way to run it in Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, boot

I recently tried out [Bootvis](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/BootVis-Download-3465.HTML) and it works great. It does exactly what I want to do, but it doesn't seem to work in Vista and Windows 7 ... is it possible to get it to work in those OS's as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use the [**Microsoft Performance Analysis Tools**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx), an even better set of tools than the old Bootvis utility. At its most basic, you can use the tools to provide you with a similar graphical display of boot performance which was provided by Bootvis.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that it takes so much more effort to install WPT on a machine. I will be using the tool on over 10 machines and probably even more over time and having to install the entire WPT takes too much time. I liked Bootvis b/c it installed in just a few seconds.

Comment: @Brian T Hannan - Well, Bootvis is a relic from Windows 2000, where the optimization was a much appreciated feature, the optimization was subsequently implemented in windows XP. However, since Vista, Bootvis is no longer supported and does not work and cannot get to work. No way around, sorry.

Comment: Do you really need to install it on so many machines? How about just install it on one machine, then use whatever you learn there and apply it to the other machines?

Comment: Now I installed this and figured out how to use it mostly, but I can't seem to get the same type of graph for booting. How do I get a trace for boot events?